# Oracle find dependent columns of function based index

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I create a query to return the user columns that are referenced from an Oracle function-based index?

Eg.  I create an index such as:

```
CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (SQRT(MY_COL));
```

For non-function based indexes I just query ALL_IND_COLUMNS such as:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_POSITION
FROM ALL_IND_COLUMNS 
WHERE INDEX_NAME = 'MY_INDEX'
```

However, this query returns COLUMN_NAME of a system generated column such as 'SYS_NC00012$' instead of the actual table column 'MY_COL' that the function-based index uses.

I know I can query DBMS_METADATA and read the returned index creation DDL

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', 'MY_INDEX') AS QUERY_STRING FROM DUAL
```

but this means I have to parse the function text which is not reliable for my purposes.

Therefore, can anyone please point me in the right direction as to how I can precisely determine which actual table columns a function-based index is defined upon?

Comment: Interesting article [Display function-based indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dictionary_query_display_function_based_index.htm).

Answer (score 3):

```
 SQL> Create table my_table ( my_col int);
 Table Created;

 SQL> CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (SQRT(MY_COL));
 Index Created 

 SQL> select
  2     table_name c1,
  3     index_name c2,
  4     column_expression c3
  5  from
  6     dba_ind_expressions
  7  where
  8     table_name='MY_TABLE';


 Table                     Index
 name                      Name                      Expression
 ------------------------ ------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 MY_TABLE                  MY_INDEX                  SQRT("MY_COL")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it returns the complete expression which must be parsed for column names. I am looking for a solution which will precisely list only the column names (without any extraneous text.)

Answer (score -1):

you can do some trick  with "COMMENT ON COLUMN" , try this

```
Create table my_table ( my_col int);

CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (SQRT(my_col));

COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_col    IS 'MY_INDEX:my_col'; -- add your index:col 

select * from ALL_COL_COMMENTS where table_NAME ='MY_TABLE'
```

you can use this trick function based index.